# When adding an ID, Sequence must have same owner as table it is linked to

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I'm trying to add an ID to the table

```
ALTER TABLE public.priz02
  ADD COLUMN id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
```

but I get an error

```
sequence must have same owner as table it is linked to
```

Current user is postgres;

Comment: please share `\d+ public.priz02` output, and what user are you using to do `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: Please connect with `psql`, run `\dt public.priz02`, then run `SELECT current_user`, then run `SELECT roleid::regrole, member::regrole, * FROM pg_auth_members;` and `SELECT version();`. Then edit the question and add the result to all queries there.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this error, you should make sure that table and sequence owner is same before adding id column.
Try this updated code;

```
-- First check the current ownership of table and sequence
SELECT table_name, table_schema, table_owner
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'priz02' AND table_schema = 'public';

SELECT column_name, column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'priz02' AND column_name = 'id';

-- Changing the sequence ownership to match the table's owner
ALTER SEQUENCE public.priz02_id_seq OWNED BY public.priz02.id;

-- Adding the 'id' column
ALTER TABLE public.priz02
ADD COLUMN id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Hope it works :)